# What is the most efficient and fastest way? to store in db and get query or go through with for loop?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, database, performance, sqlite

Im developing an objective-c app for iPhone , My web service will send me detailed list of all fashion items in a catalog page. i have refine functionality based on different criteria , such as price , type , brand and color etc. If im want to apply the refine. can anybody advice me on what is the best way to do the refine . is it better if i sore all the list in the local db temporary and do the refining by getting query from created table ? or i need to use for loop to go through and do the filtering ? or maybe i need to get the data every time from server whenever i do the filtering ? thanks in advance . i should mention that my list might have up to 1000 items.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start your project using CoreData for iOS
2. Make sure you server API has pagination, filter option

Now its never a good idea to get 1000 data from serve at once. You must have a pagination API where you fetchdata as per you need. Then store them in your coredata. Then as per the filter apply the fetch and show it on a view.

About database design it looks like you do not need many table just make sure you Normalize it  upto 2NF or 3NF. But as per you question even 2NF might solve the problem.

Finally always store all your server response to coredata then in view draw the data from core data. Make only those request which you views need, never make overloading request to server. 
Hope it was helpful.